# Adding node elements to json object in Python from NetworkX

Tags: python, json, networkx

I have a json object that I made using networkx:

```
json_data = json_graph.node_link_data(network_object)
```

It is structured like this (mini version of my output):

```
>>> json_data

{'directed': False,
 'graph': {'name': 'compose( ,  )'},
 'links': [{'source': 0, 'target': 7, 'weight': 1},
  {'source': 0, 'target': 2, 'weight': 1},
  {'source': 0, 'target': 12, 'weight': 1},
  {'source': 0, 'target': 9, 'weight': 1},
  {'source': 2, 'target': 18, 'weight': 25},
  {'source': 17, 'target': 25, 'weight': 1},
  {'source': 29, 'target': 18, 'weight': 1},
  {'source': 30, 'target': 18, 'weight': 1}],
 'multigraph': False,
 'nodes': [{'bipartite': 1, 'id': 'Icarus', 'node_type': 'Journal'},
  {'bipartite': 1,
   'id': 'A Giant Step: from Milli- to Micro-arcsecond Astrometry',
   'node_type': 'Journal'},
  {'bipartite': 1,
   'id': 'The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series',
   'node_type': 'Journal'},
  {'bipartite': 1,
   'id': 'Astronomy and Astrophysics Supplement Series',
   'node_type': 'Journal'},
  {'bipartite': 1, 'id': 'Astronomy and Astrophysics', 'node_type': 'Journal'},
  {'bipartite': 1,
   'id': 'Astronomy and Astrophysics Review',
   'node_type': 'Journal'}]}
```

What I want to do is add the following elements to each of the nodes so I can use this data as an input for [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/):

"x": 0,
"y": 0,
"size": 3
"centrality": 0

I can't seem to find an efficient way to do this though using `add_node()`. Is there some obvious way to add this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

While you have your data as a networkx graph, you could use the [set_node_attributes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) method to add the attributes (e.g. stored in a python dictionary) to all the nodes in the graph.

In my example the new attributes are stored in the dictionary `attr`:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph

# example graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["a", "b", "c", "d"])

# your data
#G = json_graph.node_link_graph(json_data)

# dictionary of new attributes
attr = {"x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "size": 3,
        "centrality": 0}

for name, value in attr.items():
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, name, value)

# check new node attributes
print(G.nodes(data=True))
```

You can then export the new graph in JSON with [node_link_data](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_data.html).